# Python How to install packages to specific directory using setuptools

Tags: python, installation, python-module

setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
 name = "Project",
 version = "1.0",
 packages = ['Project','Project.project','Project.LOG',\
            'Project.reporting','Project.templates',\
           ],

install_requires = ['django-grappelli==2.3.8','pycairo==1.10.0','django-chart-tools==0.2.1','django-admin-tools==0.4.0'],
package_data = {
    '': ['*.html','*.pyd','*.txt','*.gif','*.png','*.jpeg','*.jpg','*.css','*.js','*.py','*.html~','*.sh','*.wsgi'],

},

# metadata for upload to PyPI
author = "Me",
author_email = "me@example.com",
description = "This is an Example Package",  )
```

Now I want all the packages to be installed in dev/workspace in case of windows and /var/www in case of ubuntu OS. And I want all the install_requires to be installed in python/Lib/site-packages.
How can I do this?

Comment: You cannot specify such requirements in a `setup.py` file; that is entirely up to whomever is installing the package.

Comment: Ohk thanks.. Could you please explain how I can do this

Comment: See http://docs.python.org/2/install/index.html. I am not sure what you are trying to achieve though; using Python eggs let's you a) bundle these files in one location (optionally zipped) and use a simple library (`pkg_resources`) to access additional data files and such. See http://guide.python-distribute.org/

Answer (score 0):

I think you really want to have a look at [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/). It lets you create your own Python environment where your code and the dependencies get installed to - wherever you want and totally independent from your existing Python installation. I don't see a good reason why you would want to install dependencies in your existing Python installation.